# SIP : Detect the automatic answering agent

Tags: speech-recognition, sip, gsm, telephony

I make a call using SIP protocol to GSM number.

When I can not able to reach called number, I get SIP Error Response.

But At two situation SIP does not response any ERROR Code.

- When called number can not be reaached, some GSM operators provide  automatic telesecretary service. In this case, the call seem to be OK.
- When the called number is not in use anymore, some GSM Opeartors provide default message with an automatic agent which says "This number is no longer in use...etc". Also, in this case there is no returning SIP error code.

> Shortly I have a problem with automatic answering agents. How Can
>   understand that at the other side of called number, there is "real
>   human" not an "automatic" answering machine?

And why GSM opeartors not return any code which indicates that "this is an automatic answering machine" or "the number is not avalibale anymore"? Why there is no SIP response code for it? Or does it have?

Answer (score 3):

For the first case with the voicemail/telesecretary/automatic answering agent you will not be able to use SIP to distinguish the call. Instead you'll have to have some process listening to the media stream (RTP) and try and detect the difference between a human and an recording. One example is [Asterisk's AMD application](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+AMD) but be aware it's not an exact science.

For the second case where you receive a recorded message about not in use numbers etc. they are normally provided as progress tones which in SIP's case is received as a 183 Session Progress response. The crucial point is that you get audio on the call without the call being answered (with a SIP 2xx response). The point of this is that caller's should not get billed to listen to a recorded error message. A lot of PSTN operators will provide the ringing indication in the same manner so again if you want to detect the difference between a call that's proceeding and a call that's received an error indication you will need to capture and process the RTP audio stream which is not an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

RFC5359 has SIP Service examples. Just take a look at the document or click at below URL to check.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5359

Take a look at below URL. There is available response code for SIP.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes

It may help you to check the response.